# JavaScript: Change link value according to dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, url, dictionary, drop-down-menu

I have a list of key-values, where the key is a human-readable name and the value should fit into a link, e.g.:

```
[ 
 {"name": "The home page",        "value": "/index.php"}, 
 {"name": "The Pictures Section", "value": "/pics/index.html"},
 ...
]
```

And a list of key-values of links, e.g.:

```
[ 
 {"name" : "My Site",  "value:":"homesite.com/my_site"},
 {"name" : "His Site", "value:":"homesite.com/his_site"},
 {"name" : "Her Site", "value:":"homesite.com/her_site"}, 
 ...
]
```

I would like to have a web page with a drop down menu, and a list of links. The user will pick a name, and the list of links will be appended accordingly. For example, if the user picked `The Pictures Section`, the following list will appear:

```
<a href="homesite.com/my_site/pics/index.html">  My Site   </a>  <br>
<a href="homesite.com/his_site/pics/index.html"> His Site  </a>  <br>
<a href="homesite.com/her_site/pics/index.html"> Her Site  </a>  <br>
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is not tested, I just wrote it to give you a starting point to work from. I hope it's what you are looking for:

```
var sections = [ 
        {"name": "The home page",        "value": "/index.php"}, 
        {"name": "The Pictures Section", "value": "/pics/index.html"},
        ...
    ],
    urls = [ 
        {"name" : "My Site",  "value:":"homesite.com/my_site"},
        {"name" : "His Site", "value:":"homesite.com/his_site"},
        {"name" : "Her Site", "value:":"homesite.com/her_site"}, 
        ...
    ];

function generateSelectHtml() {
    var html = '<select id="sections" onchange="showSescion(this);">';
    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + sections[i].value + '">' + sections[i].name + '</option>';
    }
    html += "</select>";
    return html;
}

function generateSelectDom() {
    var el = document.createElement("SELECT");
    el.id = "sections";
    el.onchange = function() { showSection(el); };

    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = sections[i].value;
        option.innerText = sections[i].name;
        el.appendChild(option)
    }

    return el;
}

function showSection(box) {
    var container = document.getElementById("listContainer");
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        var item = document.getElementById("a");
        item.href = urls[i].value + box.value;
        item.innerText = urls[i].name;
        container.appendChild(item);
    }
}
```

You'll have much to change of course. What I did is:
the *generateSelectHtml* method returns html for the select box, you can add it to the dom like this:

```
document.getElementById("AN_ID").innerHTML = generateSelectHtml();
```

The *generateSelectDom* method create actual dom elements, so you can just use *appendChild* to add it to the existing dom.

The *showSection* method just outputs the selected values into an element with id *listContainer*.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arraya = [ 
 {"name": "The home page",        "value": "/index.php"}, 
 {"name": "The Pictures Section", "value": "/pics/index.html"},
 ...
]

var arrayb = [ 
 {"name" : "My Site",  "value:":"homesite.com/my_site"},
 {"name" : "His Site", "value:":"homesite.com/his_site"},
 {"name" : "Her Site", "value:":"homesite.com/her_site"}, 
 ...
]

//bind a click event to your a tags
$('a').click(function() {
//get the url of the tag
var url = $(this).attr('href');

loop through arrayb until you match the one you want
var site;
for (site in arrayb)
{
if (site.value == url)
{
break;
}
}
});

//loop through arraya matching on the name of the value matched above
var value;
for(value in arraya)
{
if (site.name == value.name)
{
break;
}
}

//this is your value
site.value;

});
```

Comment: There's no evidence of jquery usage, not in his code nor did he add any jquery related tags. If you are using jquery with your code, you might want to at least let him know about it, not to mention explaining it.

Comment: anybody not using Jquery needs to relaise it's not 2005, welcome to the revolution! Yeah your right, but it's early and I haven't had a cigarette yet

Comment: I'm not using jquery and think it's a bad library. There are better ones, just not as popular. But hey, if you enjoy being part of the LCD knock yourself out, just be aware that not everyone think like you.

Comment: Hey I have no priblems with it. It's well supported and understood, if I died in a horrible plane crash, someone needs to understand what I've written or my company may go bust...

Comment: If those are your arguments, then MooTools and Dojo qualify as well, not to mention google based lib/gwt.